# jQuery - how to select a tr that contains th's?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Title pretty much says it all.
Given a table like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</td>
    <th>Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datum 1</td>
    <td> Datum 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datum 1</td>
    <td> Datum 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to select the row which contains the th headers and no other?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Expression:

```
$(function() {
  $("tr:has(th):not(:has(td))").hide();
});
```

or even just:

```
$(function() {
  $("tr:not(:has(td))").hide();
});
```

Full example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</td>
    <th>Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datum 1</td>
    <td> Datum 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datum 1</td>
    <td> Datum 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Datum 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $(function() {
      $("tr:has(th):not(:has(td))").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is friggin amazing. That is all.

Answer (score 7):

If possible, it would be ideal to enclose your table header inside a <thead> element

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That way, selecting your table header would be as simple as:

```
$('thead');
```

Or selecting only the <tr>

```
$('thead tr');
```

Your markup would then be more readable, and styling your table becomes easier, as you can more easily target elements in the header or body of your table.

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery("tr:has(th)")
```

will select every `tr` that contains **at least one** `th`

kthxbye :)

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if it's like Dojo CSS3 queries, but you could use the first-child pseudo class, if jQuery supports it:

tr th:first-child

or

tr th:nth-child(1)

See: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:has` selector:

```
$('tr:has(th)').addClass('sample')
```

Probably won't work if you have a table with mixed `th` and `td` children though.